# How to add icon to the menu of actionbar in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar

My app has a menu (the default icon of menu is three dots) which contains several items. I want to add a icon to the menu not the icon to the actionbar. I research for 3 hours but all of the tutorials are about adding icons to the actionbar not the menu. Anybody knows how to do this or have the tutorial link?

[image]

On the top right

Comment: what menu the menu on the left or right? care to show a screen shot

Comment: I believe you want to add a icon to the options in the pop up menu, is not it?

Answer (score 0):

check this code ,

In your **.java** file add `onCreateOptionsMenu` code,

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_inbox, menu); //.xml file name
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Now, create this **menu_inbox.xml** as defined above in java code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_menu_o"  //icon with three dots
        android:orderInCategory="3"  //number of item in it
        android:title="Info"         //title on longpress on menu icon
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">   //to show menu on upper side

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_reply"
                android:title="@string/reply" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_replyall"
                android:title="@string/replyall" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_forward"
                android:title="@string/forward" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```